# Is there a way to get recent video.watches activity for a specific app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want to give the user a UI to delete activity.  I'm aware of it, but I'd rather not use the Activity social plugin.  I know that it is possible to get activity using Graph API:

`me/video.watches`

example response:

```
{ "data": [ {
    "id": "10101573590568760", 
    "from": {
        "id": "123546", 
        "name": "John Doe"
    }, 
    "start_time": "2012-02-01T18:53:34+0000", 
    "end_time": "2012-02-01T18:53:34+0000", 
    "publish_time": "2012-02-01T18:53:34+0000", 
    "application": {
        "id": "123456789123", 
        "name": "test_app"
    }, 
    "data": {
        "movie": {
            "id": "123456789123456789", 
            "url": "http://example.com/movie/My-Movie-Title", 
        "type": "video.movie", 
        "title": "My Movie Title"
        }
    }, "likes": {
        "count": 0
    }, "comments": {
        "count": 0
    }
}
```

However, for global action types, this may return other apps as well. I am only interested in my app specifically.  Is there a way to limit returned data to my app only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that video.watches only returns activity items for the current app.